# Can Gene Tonic category be seen before purchasing?

Tags: bioshock

When browsing [Gene Tonics](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_Gene_Tonics) on [Gatherer's Garden](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Gatherer%27s_Garden) the game doesn't display a tonic's category (classification), forcing the player to guess. BioShock has a limited number of slots available for each classification, starting from two.

[image]

Is there a way to find out a Gene Tonic's classification without opening BioShock Wikia (and being exposed to spoilers)?

Comment: Why do you want to know the category of the tonic anyway?

Comment: @TimmyJim: Because I don't necessarily have inventory space for tonic I've spent ADAM on, I thought my post made that evident.

Comment: If I list all the tonics and their category, will that be good enough or would that spoil it??

Comment: @TimmyJim: Would be great, the issue was that Wikia tells how each tonic can be obtained (some are hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Combat Tonics:**

- Armored Shell
- Damage Research
- Electric Flesh
- Frozen Field
- Human Inferno
- Machine Buster
- Photographer's Eye
- Static Discharge
- Wrench Jockey

**Engineering Tonics**

- Alarm Expert
- Clever Inventor
- Focused Hack
- Hacking Expert
- Prolific Inventor
- Safe Cracker
- Security Expert
- Shorten Alarms
- Speedy Hacker
- Vending Expert

**Physical Tonics**

- Bloodlust
- Booze Hound
- EVE Link
- EVE Saver
- Extra Nutrition
- Hackers Delight
- Medical Expert
- Natural Camouflage
- Scrounger
- Security Evasion
- SportBoost

Comment: Although this wasn't exactly what I asked, I got everything I wanted. And answer to my question is likely "no".